# Translation placeholder in YML format with Symfony2, is possible?

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I'm asking if it's possible to use translations in Symfony2 as, for example, `sprint_f()` PHP functions does. By using `sprint_f()` is so easy as:

```
$message = 'Are you sure to delete the %element%?';
echo sprintf($message , "element_name");
```

And the output will be: "Are you sure to delete the element_name?", that's easy. Now I have the translation file in YML format and I wrote this:

```
delete.message: Are you sure to delete the %element%?
```

But this will work? I check docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#message-placeholders) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html#component-translation-placeholders) but since I'm using [BazingaJSTranslationBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) I don't know how to get this working on this scenario. Any help or advice?

Comment: Did you try the example given in the `Readme` of the bundle. Right on the link you provided. [The docs say](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#message-placeholders--parameters): `will replace each "%foo%" in the message by "bar".`

Comment: @ferdynator yes, you're right but this is not my concern since I ask for how to did this in the `messages.en.yml` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `messages.en.yml`:

```
delete.message: Are you sure to delete the %element%?
```

Now call it in `js`:

```
Translator.trans('delete.message', { "element" : "YOUR VALUE" }, 'messages');
```

Explanation found in the [BazingaJsTranslationBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#message-placeholders--parameters) docs.